# How to selectively allow queries in apollo-server-express?

Tags: typescript, authorization, apollo-server, typegraphql

The majority of queries and mutations that my server is handling require authorization. However, there are a select few resolvers that should be public i.e. sign-in, register, forgot-password. How can I selectively allow these resolves to be hit and *by default* have an authorization gate for the rest?

Currently using apollo-server-express & type-graphql.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there you can user `@Authorized()` decorator with `authChecker` function on the schema definition,

Here is the example code

```
import { Request } from "express";
import { ApolloServer, } from "apollo-server-express";
          
export interface ExpressContext {
  req: Request;
}

export const userAuthChecker: AuthChecker<ExpressContext> = async (
  { root, args, context: { req }, info },
  roles,
) => {
  //Perform your own logic here 
  return false; // true if the user is authorized   
};

  // Add your Auth checker middleware to your buildSchema method
const schema = await buildSchema(
  {
    authChecker: userAuthChecker,
    resolvers: [...yourresolvers]
  }
);

// then define your context from the apollo server setup
const apolloserver = new ApolloServer({
  schema, context: (ctx) => {
    return ctx;
  }
});

// After Completing the above this is how you put it in action, with @Authorized() // decorator
@ObjectType()
export class Resolver extends BaseEntity {
  ...
  @Authorized('Admin') // <---
  @Query(returns => [MyModel])
  artists() {
    return value;
  })
}
```